# Backbone JS - How to write a reusable component

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to write a reusable component as part of my Backbone app. Fundamentally I want to write a form filter helper so I can:

- call a func inside a view js file which will create a drop-down which can listen to changes and then trigger changes in data and refreshes the view.

Ultimately I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
// generic view.js

// to spawn a dropdown
formFilter('select', data);

// to spawn a series of checkboxes
formFilter('checkbox', data);
```

Obviously the module code would listen for events and handle the work.

My question is, what is the standard way of creating a reusable component? Google isn't giving me much and the #documentcloud IRC isn't particularly active.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the information you've provided in your question, it's not easy to say how your particular component would be best componentized. However, one powerful strategy for reusability is **mixins**.

Simply you define the methods in a simple object literal, such as:

```
Mixins.filterable = {
  filterForm: function(selector, data) {
    this.$(selector)...
  }
}

Mixins.sortable = {
  sortForm: function(selector) {
    this.$(selector)...
  }
}
```

And then you can mix them into any `View`'s prototype:

```
_.extend(FooView.prototype, Mixins.filterable, Mixins.sortable);
```

The mixin methods will then be available in all instances of `FooView`.

```
render: function() {
  //..
  this.filterForm('select', this.model);
}
```

Because the mixin methods will be bound to the context of the view instance, you can refer to `this`, and by logical extension, `this.$el`, inside the mixin methods. This will enable you to listen to the view's events:

```
Mixins.filterable = {
  filterForm: function(selector, data) {
    this.$(selector).on('change', this._handleFilterChange);
  },

  _handleFilterChange: function(e) {
    //..
  }      
}
```

To make the methods available on all views, mix them into the `Backbone.View` prototype instead:

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, Mixins.filterable, Mixins.sortable);
```

Comment: I have a question in regards to extending functionality to all views through `Backbone.View.prototype`. Where do I put this code in the architecture of a backbone application?